# I wonder what preposition to use with 'to give'

Tags: prepositions

[image]
The 7th question.
I wonder what preposition to use with  'to give'

Comment: We need specifics. Are there choices that you can use? What do you think the answer is? Why do you think that?

Comment: I can't find the rule but my choices are: 'given me up on my children' or 'given me to my children'. Does at least one of them sound natural ?

Comment: Please edit your question, adding these details as well as any others you have.

Comment: Could you just tell me the answer. Then I'll delete it immediately.

Comment: Deleting your question immediately after you receive an answer is forbidden. Please type the question. Do not include an image.

Comment: @Gogehat There are many prepositions. We need to see the full sentence. You mention _child**ren**_ even though your picture shows _child_. If we give you the wrong advice due to a lack of information, you won't be helped as a learner.

Comment: @Em.: *Including* an image is fine, as long as it's not just a picture of text. But it does need to be described with text as best as possible, or in this case, replaced with a plain text transcription.

Answer (score 1):

With the given information, "given me [to] my children" is the most natural fit. "Given me [up] on my children" doesn't make sense.

Perhaps your assignment meant to read, "God has given my children to me". Regardless, I'd use "to" as the preposition for that phrase. Hope that helps!